# Numbering MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql

Using the following MySQL query:

```
    SELECT  SUM(vg.count) AS sum, vg.code, lh.luchthavencode
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS COUNT, vg.vertrekluchthaven AS code
    FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
    WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <= NOW( ) 
    GROUP BY vg.vertrekluchthaven

    UNION  

        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, vg.aankomstluchthaven AS code
        FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg  
        WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW()
        GROUP BY vg.aankomstluchthaven
    ) vg
    INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh
    ON  lh.luchthavenID = vg.code
    GROUP BY vg.code
    ORDER BY sum DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

I am trying to figure out how to number the results so that when I display them on a PHP page, it's easier to understand the results.

For example, currently my results would show something like this:

```
Sum   |   Code  |   Luchthavencode
41        121             MSP
26        91              AMS
9         246             ORD
8         116             DTW
6         169             LHR
6         142             IAH
6         346             SYR
5         149             JFK
5         13              AKL
5         417             FRA
```

What I'd like is to have it list like this:

```
No. |   Sum   |   Code  |   Luchthavencode
1       41        121             MSP
2       26        91              AMS
3       9         246             ORD
4       8         116             DTW
5       6         169             LHR
6       6         142             IAH
7       6         346             SYR
8       5         149             JFK
9       5         13              AKL
10      5         417             FRA
```

Is this best achieved through MySQL query or via PHP output?

I've tried adding this to my SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num , but it numbers them like this: 45, 4, 47, 18, 34, 24, 56, 27, 2, 63

Edited to include Output PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo"  <table width='100px' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
    echo "  <tbody>";
    echo "    <tr>";
    echo "      <td width='60px'><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;".$row['luchthavencode']."</strong></td>";
    echo "      <td width='30px'><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;".$row['sum']."</strong></td>";
    echo "    </tr>";
    echo "  </tbody>";
    echo "</table>";    
}
```

Comment: already have tons of duplicates for this, can't you just use a counter increment in php?

Comment: If I knew that was possible I would not have posted the question.

Comment: You guys on here always assume people know everything. I've done numerous google searches and have been unable to figure it out. That's why I come to this site.

Comment: Show us the PHP code that you use to process this query and output the result

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I've added my current PHP code. I'm working on trying a couple of things. But this is what I've got so far, in its very basic form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want one table containing this data so I fixed what I assumed was an error in the table building as well as adding a counter

```
echo "<table width='100px' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
echo "<tbody>";

$line = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$line</td>";
    echo "<td width='60px'><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;".$row['luchthavencode']."</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='30px'><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;".$row['sum']."</strong></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $line++;
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: yes, this works perfectly. Yes, the table was also causing me problems. I'm still learning how to do PHP and just as I had a handle on mysql things moved to mysqli and i'm trying to relearn.... challenging! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use this code at the start of you query to get a number of row

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
```

Comment: I've tried this. It does not give them correct numbering.

Comment: how is returning the numbers??

Comment: It numbers them in this "order" 45, 4, 47, 18, 34, 24, 56, 27, 2, 63

Comment: or in PHP maybe is easier, if you will print your results try `$count=1; foreach($result as $row { echo count; echo $row['your_columns']; $count++;}`

Comment: This will add the number before the sort is done and therefore would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable should work, try this check if it works:

```
SELECT
    @rowno := @rowno + 1 AS `No.`
    SUM(vg.count) AS sum,
    vg. CODE,
    lh.luchthavencode
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
            vg.vertrekluchthaven AS CODE
        FROM
            tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
        WHERE
            vg.vertrekdatum2 <= NOW()
        GROUP BY
            vg.vertrekluchthaven
        UNION
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
            vg.aankomstluchthaven AS CODE
        FROM
            tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
        WHERE
            vg.vertrekdatum2 <= NOW()
        GROUP BY
            vg.aankomstluchthaven
    ) vg
INNER JOIN tbl_luchthaven lh ON lh.luchthavenID = vg.CODE
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rowno := 0) rn
GROUP BY
    vg. CODE
ORDER BY
    sum DESC
LIMIT 10
```